# How to completely disable/remove cups on Ubuntu snaps?

Tags: printing, snap

I don't have a printer and I don't need `cups`, so I removing it by

```bash
sudo snap remove cups
```

but every time I reboot my PC, Ubuntu 23.04 keep installing it via `snap`.

What should I do?
[image]

Comment: you need to stop cups first and do a "purge", Oh and check if `avahi` is active, nuke that too.

Comment: It's install via `snap` so there is no `apt` to `purge`, I'm already stop and disabled `avahi`

Comment: You must remove the deb CUPS packages, too. That's what installs the Snap.

Comment: @mehdiMj do check that. you probably do ;)

Comment: @user535733 I tried `sudo apt purge cups` and the response is `Package 'cups' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: CUPS is multiple packages. See `apt depends cups`

Comment: Thank you for your response but `cups` is on an other package manager and  managed by `snap`, why you referring to `apt`?

Comment: You should probably read https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/cups-snap-call-for-testing/21266 to understand what is going on.

Comment: Okay, let me ask in other way. I `sudo apt purge cups*` and `sudo snap remove cups` the **cups** program. How is it even possible it show up in couple of days later on my system. I remove other packages too (I add it to my main question)

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1486694/edit). Try to ask a single clear answerable question. Avoid asking hyperbolic or rhetorical questions that you don't really want answers to ("*How is XYZ possible?*"). Seems like you really want to uninstall all of CUPS, both apt and snap. If packages are re-installing, then what do your logs say about it?

Comment: Yes I do, I really like to remove them. If I don't have printer/scanner so don't like to have them on my system too. I think I have found a solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I remove `cups` on `snap` and remove any package relate to **cups** [according to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177458/remove-cupsd-completely-from-linux-mint), I hope it will work.

```bash
dpkg -l | grep -i cup | grep ii
```

[image]